# Property 'prototype' does not exist on type

Tags: typescript

I want to add method to prototype of WebScoket. But typescript gives error saying 'Property 'prototype' does not exist on type 'WebSocketExtended''

```
const WS: WebSocketExtended = require('ws');
import {Server} from 'ws';
let ws: Server;

interface WebSocketExtended extends WebSocket {
    json(d: any): void
}

export function start(server){
  ws = new Server({server: server});
  ws.on('connection', onConnection);
};

function onConnection(socket:WebSocketExtended) {

    socket.json({data:'some data'});
}

WS.prototype.json = function (d) {
  try {
    d = JSON.stringify(d);
    this.send(d);
  } catch (e) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In typescript interfaces are open to extension. That means you can add new properties on them just by declaring them in multiple places, the compiler will take care to merge them all into one coherent interface.

As such what you need to do to add a new property on the **WebSocket** interface is redeclare that interface with the extra property.

Like this:

```js
interface WebSocket {
    json(param: string): any;

}

WebSocket.prototype.json = function (param: string) {
    return param;
}
```

Comment: This works when included in the same file. but when I move the interface declaration to a seperate file, I get error on socket.json(). Undefined method

Comment: you need to import that file in this file first, so the definitions and prototype get added. an `import './path/to/otherfile';` should do it. Preferably you can do this somewhere at the root of your project (if it needs to be used in multiple places).

Comment: Actually it doesn't work in the same file as well. I tried all variants that came to my mind. I see errors in all cases. Could you check this one on your side? https://codeshare.io/ayDgVo